# My selenium program fails to find element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to perform a web automatization with python and selenium in chrome.
The thing is im trying to locate a button which has not id or class name.

**The xpath is:**

```
 //*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/span[1]
```

**And the html code is**

```
<span class="SectionMethod" onclick="window.location.href=&quot;explorer/explorer.aspx?root=user&quot;;" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;color:CadetBlue;">Open</span>
```

It's a button called open, but there are other buttons like that one with the same text and class so i cant locate by text.

**This is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())

driver.get("..............") 


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/span[1]')
```

**This is the error i am getting:**

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Form1"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64).
```

Comment: Make sure you waited until the form is loaded by using the Expected conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely you are looking for an element before it has loaded. As per [the example from the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

In your case:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

Will be

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/span[1]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your correct xpath is:

```
//span[@class='SectionMethod' and text() = 'Open']
```

[image]

Comment: it gives this error


NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='SectionMethod' and text() = 'Open']"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: Try to use this Xpath with wait, as Reedinationer recommended below.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are trying to `click()` on the `<span>` element with text as **Open** and to achieve that you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.SectionMethod[onclick*='explorer/explorer']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='SectionMethod' and contains(@onclick,'explorer/explorer')][text()='Open']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Additionally, as you are using `chrome=75.0.3770.100` you need to update *ChromeDriver* to [ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (2019-06-13)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.90/)

Comment: it says timeout exception when trying that